# SwiftUI: How to use withAnimation in a ScrollView?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, scrollview

I've been trying to animate a ScrollView using ScrollViewReader and withAnimation.

I can't figure out why these two animations are not working, either from Button or .onAppear?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollView2: View {
    
    @State private var scrollText = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 30)) {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(99, anchor: .center)
                    }
                }
                
                ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                    Text(String(index))
                        .id(index)
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 30)) {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(scrollText ? 99 : 1, anchor: .center)
                    }
                    scrollText.toggle()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. Make sure you are in a 'Live Preview' if you are previewing on a the canvas.

Comment: As it was already reported only .default animation works in such scenario irrelative of which one you provided.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your comments. @nicksarno what I was looking for was the 30 sec duration for the animation that is sadly not working.

Comment: @Asperi, thanks I tried to replace .linear by .default, working great but not with duration :/

Comment: @Jean-SébastienWallez Thanks for the update! I posted an option below.

Comment: @nicksarno wow man thanks so much for putting the work here! Works great too! Trying to think how I could skip these first 40 rows to have the animation starting right away.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just change the 'counter' to begin at 40. Obviously, if you change the content (instead of just numbers), the size of each item will change and you'll have to adjust again. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Because duration doesn't seem to work with withAnimation yet, I had to be a bit hacky to get the animation effect I wanted.

Here's what I did:

1. I added a ScrollViewReader to my ScrollView
2. I used ForEach and added IDs to my items in my ScrollView
3. Used an .offset and .animation modifiers to animate the
   ScrollView itself (not the items in it)
4. Used .scrollTo within .onAppear to move at launch the ScrollView
   to an item further away from the start to allow the user to both
   scroll back and forward the items, even with the ScrollView being
   itself animated from right to left

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ProView: View {
    
    @State private var scrollText = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
//            VStack {
//                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
//                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
//            }
//            
//            VStack {
//                
//                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "wave-1", withExtension: "mp4")!)) {
//                    VStack {
//                        Image("pro-text")
//                            .resizable()
//                            .frame(width: 200, height: .infinity)
//                            .scaledToFit()
//                    }
//                }
//                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
//                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300)
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    ScrollViewReader { value in
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 5) {
                            
                            ForEach(0 ..< 100) { i in
                                
                                HStack {
                                    Image("benefit-1")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-2")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-3")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-4")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-5")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-6")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-7")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-8")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-9")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                    
                                    Image("benefit-10")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                }
                                .id(i)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .offset(x: scrollText ? -10000 : 20)
                        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 300).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                        .onAppear() {
                            value.scrollTo(50, anchor: .trailing)
                            scrollText.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like duration doesn't work within withAnimation. Alternatively, I created a function that executes a repeating Timer that fires over 30 seconds, calling scrollTo withAnimation on each loop.

```
struct ScrollView2: View {
    
    @State private var scrollText = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                    animateWithTimer(proxy: scrollView)
                }
                ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                    Text(String(index))
                        .id(index)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func animateWithTimer(proxy: ScrollViewProxy) {
        let count: Int = 100
        let duration: Double = 30.0
        let timeInterval: Double = (duration / Double(count))
        var counter = 0
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            withAnimation(.linear) {
                proxy.scrollTo(counter, anchor: .center)
            }
            counter += 1
            if counter >= count {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
        timer.fire()
    }
}
```

Note: There is a delay when you press the button initially because when it tries to scrollTo the first ~40 of numbers, they are already high on the screen and the scrollView doesn't need to scroll anywhere to center them. You can update the timeInterval and counter variables as needed.